# Cannot unhide a button except in ViewDidLayoutSubviews()

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, iboutlet, viewdidlayoutsubviews

I have a `UIButton` that should only be appearing sometimes. In the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` I did the following:

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    clearButtonOutlet.hidden = true
```

However, when I try to do `clearButtonOutlet.hidden = false` in other places, the button will not reappear.

At first I thought maybe my constraints were messed up but this makes the button reappear:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    clearButtonOutlet.hidden = true
    clearButtonOutlet.hidden = false
```

Why can I not make the button reappear in other places?

EDIT 1: Where I am trying to make the button reappear:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    //some stuff
    switch textField.tag {

        //tag = 3 is the when I want the clear button to show
    case 3:
        //launch the date picker
        launchDatePicker(textField)

        //once DatePicker is launched, show the clear button
        clearButtonOutlet.hidden = false
    default: break
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that does not work?  Preferably the entree class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just setting it hidden won't do everything, you need to get the view to redraw. I would set `clearButton.hidden = true` when you create the button not in viewDidLayout or it will always hide when the view lays out again (resize on iPad or landscape orientation). Then in your `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method I would set the `clearButton.hidden = false` like you have and then call `view.setNeedsLayout()` to force it to relayout and draw.